# How can we extend Sitecore Quick Search(Instant Search) to use custom index instead of system index?

Tags: sitecore

As told in [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sitecore_search_and_indexing-a4.pdf) "Sitecore Quick Search" uses the system index to perform instant search.

How to point "Sitecore Quick Search" to use custom index while searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instant search eventually starts the core `search` pipeline, which is used by other types of searches within the backend. One of the processors of `search` pipeline (`SearchSystemIndex`) instructs the system explicitly to search the `system` index.

As long as this is a core of search functionality I would not recommend you changing the logic there. If you still decide to go this way, then inserting a custom processor into the `search` pipeline seems to be the starting point. I suspect there to be a number of unexpected things to overcome in order not to break the way search works throughout the system.

Comment: Thanks!!! I added a new processor "SearchMyIndex" after the SearchSystemIndex and it worked!!!!